# Why the following result is the output? Are class fields don't get initalized before the constructor?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, initialization, overriding

I want to understand why the result of the following code:

```
public class Base {
    private int member1 = 1;
    private int member2 = 2;

    public Base() {
        System.out.println("base ctor");
        print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(member1 + "" + member2);
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private int member3 = 3;
    private int member4 = 4;

    public Derived() {
        System.out.println("derived ctor");
        print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(member3 + "" + member4);
    }
}

class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Derived d = new Derived();
    }
}
```

is:

```
base ctor
00
derived ctor
34
```

- the derived class's constructor implicitly calls its super
- constructor. super's (base class) constructor prints "base ctor"

super's constructor calls `print()` - which prints `member 1 , member 2`
I thought that member1 and member2 already initialized because as I thought that I know, when we create an object the order of the things is
static fields & blocks go first (if its the first load of the class)
then instance things (like fields & members) go by order, which means what comes before in the order of the code.

Here - the fields come before the constructor, which means it should run and already initialize member1 and member2 before it reach print.

Why does it print `0 0`?

Does it even go to the print of `Base` or it goes to the print of `Derived`? because it gets called from the constructor of `Base` so I don't get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `print` method in `Derived` twice - once during the `Base` constructor, and once during the `Derived` constructor. That's because `Derived.print()` overrides `Base.print()`.

So this expectation:

> `super`'s constructor calls `print()` - which prints `member 1` , `member 2`

... is incorrect. It's calling the `print()` implementation in `Derived`, which prints `member3` and `member4`. Those haven't been initialized yet.

The order of execution is:

- Base class field initializers
- Base class constructor body
- Derived class field initializers
- Derived class constructor body

If you just change your two `print` methods to `print1` and `print2` (and change the calling code appropriately) then it prints:

```
base ctor
12
derived ctor
34
```

... as you expected.

Comment: The question is why, why is the `print()` call in the `Base` constructor actually runs the `print()` which is in the `Derived` class? I know that the object is a `new Derived`, but does it mean that even calls from the super constructor will get to the Derived implementation?

Comment: Because you have overriden the `print` method in your `Derived` class (same method signature as in your `Base` class). If you rename the methods as @JonSkeet suggested to `print1` and `print2` you wouldn't have such issue.

Comment: @NoobCoder: Yes, the method implementation used doesn't change over an object's lifetime. It's a `Derived` object right from the start, so any call to `print` will call `Derived.print`, even in the `Base` constructor .

Comment: @JonSkeet didn't know that, thank you. What about if we declared the object as `Base obj = new Derived` and we would call `print()` in the base constructor? It's so weird for me to think that if we call `print()` in X class **constructor** (which I thought is "holy" because this is actually creates the object), then the actual `print()` that will be executed is other.

Comment: @NoobCoder: It would be very easy for you to test that yourself - but no, the type of the variable you're assigning to makes no difference. The type of the object, which is what's responsible for determining which method implementation is used, remains the same throughout its lifetime.